# iOS APNS device ID not matching Passbook Device ID

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, passbook

I have an (PhoneGap) App that will successfully get Passbook Passes and will also successfully receive Push Notifications separate from Passbook (when faking the device ID).

The problem I am having is that the device ID passbook sends to register the device does not match the APNS device ID. And even worse, I cannot for the life of me make the device get a different ID (even after multiple APNS certs and the uninstalling, setting date ahead technique)

- Launch app
- APNS yes/no?  Yes!
- Call for APNS device ID is received (same one as always)
- Go ahead and create passbook pass, add pass
- Passbook makes callback (register device) with device ID received from Apple different than APNS device ID

Both are using the same CSR file to create APNS and pass type id, an active provisioning profile (with push and passbook enabled).  I'm not sure what the problem is, but half the problem is that APNS will not give it a new ID.

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm assuming I'm not crazy and the device IDs should match.

Thanks

Comment: What iOS version are you using?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness  Wouldn't it make sense? If the pass is locked to an app and the APNS is locked to an app and the same device asks for a device ID for that app, wouldn't it be the same?  Otherwise you would need device id for push notifications for updating passbook as well as device id for push notifications in general.  Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, this is expected.

Refer to  [Passbook Programming Guide: Updating a Pass](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW59)
specifically -

> The device library identifier is a Passbook-specific shared secret between the user’s device and your web server. It is not related to the device identifier (UDID). The device identifies itself with a different ID to different servers and it may change its ID at any time. Its purpose is to allow efficient communication between the device and your server, not to let your server keep a list of of what passes are currently installed on a device. The device library identifier uniquely identifies a device and indicates that the entity making the request is authorized to make such a request.

and also from [Local and Push Notitifcation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW3)

> Note: A device token is not the same thing as the device UDID returned by the identifierForVendor or uniqueIdentifier property of UIDevice or any other similar properties such as the advertisingIdentifier property of ASIdentifierManager.

Apple goes to some lengths to prevent the facilitation of *unintentional* tracking, so different frameworks will return different device identifiers on the same device for a given App.  Different Apps on the same device will also obtain different identifiers from the same frameworks.

*EDIT* - The Pushtoken (also supplied at registration) is used to identify the device in subsequent push notifications, not the DeviceLibraryID, but the concept is the same - this identifier is unique to other identifiers on the same device.

Comment: Yeah I knew it was not the same as UDID, I figured that anything related to an app (passbook) would all fall under one device id.  So if I understand correctly, for a push notification to the device I would send to one device id, and then to tell them to update their pass, I would send a push to a different device id?  It makes sense

Comment: correct, and to clarify my answer it is the push token, not the device library ID that is used in the push notification to identify the device